# Как для первого элемента img на странице задать title и alt

Tags: javascript, html

Как для первого элемента  img на странице задать title и alt

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вам подойдет такой вариант:

```js
var firstImage = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
firstImage.setAttribute("title", "first");
firstImage.setAttribute("alt", "img");
console.log("id: " + firstImage.id + " title: " + firstImage.title +  " alt: " + firstImage.alt)
```

```html
<div> 
  <img id="secongImg">
  <img id="firstImg">
  <img id="thirdImg">
</div>
```